# How to get the result value number that maybe in any part of a string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, tesseract, tesseract.js

I use `tesseract.js` to get the image text in node js and in my case the strings are like this :

[image: esr14]

**Tesseract rendered text :**

```
ESR 14 fm
```

[image: esr15]

**Tesseract rendered text :**

```
ESR Less Than 10 mm/1st Hour 15
```

I want to get the **ESR** value which is under the the **Results** column and in the first case is after the `ESR` (14) string and in the second case is at the end of the string (15) .

I tried something like this with javascript split function which doesn't work for the second case and gives me the characters `Le` :

```
     let result;
          if (text.split("esr")[1]) {
            result = text.split("esr")[1];
          } else if (text.split("ESR")[1]) {
            result = text.split("ESR")[1];
          } else if (text.split("Esr")[1]) {
            result = text.split("Esr")[1];
          }
```

How can I get the actual result value in both cases and not get other characters in both strings ?

Comment: Please _delete_ the images and instead include the starting text after the OCR has been run.

Comment: I don't think if its possible. your data seems dynamic and you need some sort of a table to read the data. filtering knows texts might work too. like "Less Than *" or "more than *"

Comment: what exactly do you want to get from the given example string? literally what would be the desired result for `ESR Less Than 10 mm/1st Hour 15` ?

Comment: @FlashThunder I've added some images to the question I want the result value which in first string is 14 and in the second string is 15 .

Comment: check my answer, hopefully it fits your needs, but if you got some numeric values after, it's simply impossible to check if it's a result or not if you don't have any predefined formats

Comment: 1.- Use tesseract to produce a result which resembles the original layout (for example, combining sparse text to pdf `tesseract –psm 11 pdf` and layout `pdftotext -layout`
2.- Then, search for "result" in the top lines, save the position and then search for a number value in the same position at the "ESR" line

Comment: @PA. Thanks alot for your time can you please post an answer to my question with more details on how you would solve the issue ? thanks again .

Comment: @PA. I don't think it will work, as there are multiple results that can vary (the selection of results), so generally making a layout from it will not help at all.

Comment: @FlashThunder I think it will, give it a try, and parametrize the target position with a certain boundary around "Result" position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe simply use regex for searching the last space followed by number?

```js
function checkESR(str){
  let matched = str.match(/ESR.*(\s[0-9]+)/);
  if(matched){
    return parseInt(matched[1]);
  }else{
    return null;
  }
}

console.log(checkESR("ESR Less Than 10 mm/1st Hour 15"));
console.log(checkESR("ESR 14 fm"));
console.log(checkESR("some other stuff before with result 11\nESR Less Than 10 mm/1st Hour 15\nsome stuff after with result 17"));
```